# variable in controller not passed to view, using with()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass on a `$image` variable to my view (gallerij.blade.php) but it will not work. I get a error message saying: "Undefined variable: image". I do not know how to solve this world.

I have already looked for a solution on Stack Overflow, but I could not find any solution for my answer. I have also looked on the Laracast website. But I could not find a answer there. Finally, I have also asked a fellow programmer to see if he could find a solution, but he also didn't know what was going wrong.

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\gallerijs;

class GalerijController extends Controller
{
    public function Retrieve(){
    $g = gallerijs::find(1);
    $image = chunk_split(base64_encode($g->afbeelding));
    return view('gallerij ')->with($image);
}
}
```

My view:

```
@extends ('Layout')
@section('title')
    Galerij
@endsection

@section('content')


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="{{asset('Pictures/'.$image)}}" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="{{asset('Pictures/loremipsum2.jpg')}}" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="{{asset('Pictures/loremipsum3.jpg')}}" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>



@endsection
```

I try to use the variable in the first `img src`.

Hopefully I have given you enough information so that you can help me finding a solution.

Comment: Try like `return view('gallerij')->with('image', $image);` See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply, it worked. But the image is not being retrieved out of the database, do you know how I can solve this? If you want you can answer the question not in the comments so that I can accept it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903572/display-blob-image-laravel-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
return view('gallerij ')->with($image);
```

to:

```
return view('gallerij ', compact('image'));
```

I find this to be the cleanest way to pass variables to the view while retaining the variable name.

You can use `with()` but you must reiterate the variable name (ie: `->with('image', $image)`)

Or you can define an array of variables to pass as a second argument to view (ie: `view('view.template', ['image' => $image]`).

That's were the compact function comes in handy.  It will create an array from a list of variable names using the variable name as the key (ie: `compact('image')` creates `['image' => $image]`)

Comment: Hi wheelmaker, thank you for your answer. I would use what you have said but I am instructed to use with() (homework assignment). Now that I am commenting you, do you also know why my image is not being retrieved from the database? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: have you tried `dd($g)` after the `$g = gallerijs::find(1);` call to see what the results of find are?

Comment: Hi, it returns the following: gallerijs {#232 ▼
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "gallerijs"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:4 [▶]
  #original: array:4 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: On your view it looks like you are just trying to get the name of the image file as $image so you can display it in an image tag... does your $gallerijs object have a photo name associated with an image on your server? what exactly are you doing here `chunk_split(base64_encode($g->afbeelding));`

Comment: Since this is another questions differend then what the first question was. You can see my new question about this subject here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826863/image-not-retrieved-from-database. Thank you for your help until now!

Answer (score 0):

Please user as image array
 like

```
public function Retrieve(){
    $g = gallerijs::find(1);
    $image = chunk_split(base64_encode($g->afbeelding));
    return view('gallerij ')->with('image',$image);
}
```