# Image not retrieved from database

Tags: php, laravel

Recently I have been trying to retrieve a image from the database, but it will not work. I am trying to do this with Laravel but I am struggling so I decided to ask the Stack Overflow community to see if they had a solution for me.

There are similar questions like this one on Stack Overflow. But I could not find one where the answers were the one I was looking for. I have also looked on the Laracast website, it helped me a bit but still not enough. Finally, I have read Stack Overflow question: [Display BLOB image Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903572/display-blob-image-laravel-4). But this did not help me as well.

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\gallerijs;

class GalerijController extends Controller
{
    public function Retrieve(){
    $g = gallerijs::find(1);
    dd($g);
    $image = chunk_split(base64_encode($g->afbeelding));
    return view('gallerij')->with('image', $image);
}
}
```

My view:

```
@extends ('Layout')
@section('title')
    Galerij
@endsection

@section('content')


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="{{asset('Pictures/'.$image)}}" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="{{asset('Pictures/loremipsum2.jpg')}}" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="{{asset('Pictures/loremipsum3.jpg')}}" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>


@endsection
```

What my `dd($g)` returns:

```
gallerijs {#232 ▼
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "gallerijs"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:4 [▶]
  #original: array:4 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Ì hope to have given you enough information so that you can help me solve the problem.

Comment: your view is trying to load an image from a public/Pictures folder on your webserver but you seem to be pulling an actual image from the database, are you storing the image file in the database or just a path or file name?

Comment: The image is stored in the database

Comment: it sounds like you've skipped over a few steps in your assignment here, you're going to need to write the image to the public/Pictures directory and then just pass the name to your view as $image if you want your view to load the image the way it is, this is honestly probably beyond the scope of troubleshooting normally provided by stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Changing you blade template image tag to something similar to this, should solve your problem. Usually i would always save images in traditional folders. This does the trick for your domain.

```
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64, {{ $image }}" />
```